# D3: problems with node = vis.selectAll(".node")

Tags: d3.js

This is a hard one to explain but hopefully its an easy one to answer...bear with me...i considered js fiddling it but I would have to rewrite a lot of code as the data it uses is from my internal server.

I have written a long amount of js to model a network map and its too long, and the essence of the issue is that I can draw the map with initial data fine but it corrupts sometimes when I update it - namely when I remove nodes from the original map (though I can add new nodes fine)

I believe the issues are due to the way I have drawn the svg objects.

I am trying to work d3 out on the fly a bit so I may have deviated unintentionally from what is right.

First off I define vis (window.vis as it is now so I can test it with the console) - which I think some examples use the variable svg for.

```
  window.vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .append('svg:g')
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .append('svg:g');
```

then I do some other stuff, creating nodeArray (an array of the nodes I want) and linkArray( an array of links I want) then I draw the nodes and links:

```
link = vis.selectAll("line").data(linkArray);
        link.enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", function (d, i) {
            if (d.class == 'link reallink') {
                return '0.8';
            } else {
                return '0';
            };
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", function (d, i) {
            if (d.class == 'link reallink') {
                return '3';
            } else {
                return '0';
            };
        })
        .style("stroke", function (d, i) { return d.color; });



        node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(nodeArray);
        node.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", function (d) { return d.class })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id })
        .call(force.drag);


        //append to each node an svg circle element
        vis.selectAll(".realnode").append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", function (d, i) { 
            if (d.status != "0") { 
                return r*2; 
            } else { 
                if (d.iconimage == "") { return r; } else { return 1; } 
            }
        })
        .style("fill", function (d, i) { if (d.status != "0") { if (d.status == "1") { return "#ff0000"; } else { return "#FFBF00"; } } else { return "#FFFFFF"; }})
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
            if (d.style !== 'filled') { return d.color; };
        })
        .style("stroke-width", "4");


        //attach images to the nodes
        vis.selectAll(".realnode").append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.iconimage; })
        .attr("x", -16)
        .attr("y", -16)
        .attr("width", 32)
        .attr("height", 32);
```

*NB: node classes I use are node (all nodes) and realnode (real objects) (as I also model the text labels later on as a different class labelnode).  nodeArray is just an array of objects formatted as nodes and linkArray is just an array of links.*

You can see that I define 'link' and 'node' - pretty much as all the examples do - but I found  circles and images did not append properly if I used node.selectAll(".realnode").append... but works fine if I use vis.selectAll(".realnode").append... so I just did that and moved on

However I think I need to solve this lack of understanding!

Later on when I delete nodes out of nodeArray and links out of linkArray, and update the display I am again utilising the 'node' and 'link' objects in a haphazard mix with 'vis' - and at that point it all goes wrong and corrupts.  Although the svg element on the page still has the right objects defined, images swap, text swaps and the links float off on their own without the nodes!  I have checked nodeArray and linkArray and they are completely correct, and if I use the "new" data after the update as the original data when I first load the page it renders fine so I am fairly confident of my data objects.

I think the best way is for me to answer any questions and update this as I go along, as I hope someone will just look at this and see what I am doing wrong.  The really annoying thing is the initial page load always works perfectly but the updating of data is taking me longer than the whole initial page draw code from scratch!

Thanks

--Chris

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `.data()` call after the `.selectAll(".realnode")`?

Comment: it works initially..don't dispute you are right but I don't understand why if thats the case it works at all?

Comment: It looks like there are some elements with this class already, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code and the description right, the nodeArray has some items with class `node` and others with class `realnode`. When you create the nodes, you are selecting only the nodes of class `node`, this allows the creation of groups of each class, but bounds the selection only to the groups of class `node`. I think that you need to create the nodes with both classes

```
nodes = vis.selectAll('g')
   .data(nodeArray)
   ...
   .call(force.drag);
```

And then operate over selections based in the class of the elements:

```
nodes.selectAll('g.realnode')
   // ... set attributes here
```

Also, I would suggest using css for setting the attributes of link and node classes:

```
links = vis.selectAll('line')
    .classed('real-link', function(d) { return d.class == 'link reallink'; });
```

and in the css:

```
svg .real-link {
    stroke-opacity: 0.8;
    stroke-width: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, I need to give it a go and see if it fixes the problem (hopefully) or just improves the code (definitely!).  That said, all nodes are class node, but the real nodes are node & realnode and the labels are node & labelnode, and likewise for links.   But doing it this way might allow me to maintain separate variables for each type of node, which might well work better.  I still don't really understand why what I have works at all, and why if it does work subsequent updates to nodeArray and linkArray and rerunning this code corrupts the model?

Comment: (I would have upvoted the answer but I need more rep to do so)

Comment: To assign more than one class to an element, don't use attr("class", function), use the classed("class", function) method instead: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-classed.

Comment: You can also use class and put spaces between the classes .. I believe it's a shorthand that gets expanded to classed?

Comment: I have tried various ideas around this and the generally I still get the initial draw to work but it still corrupts when I redraw.  I have worked out one mistake I made, not using enter() when I add new nodes so I append duplicate elements onto g nodes.  However, I'm just not cracking this.  What I'm going to do is write a complete test from scratch on jsfiddle and update this question / pst as a new question once I reproduce it, if nor no other reason than to prove that it is a reproducible issue.

Comment: All, thanks for your input on this.  I couldn't really progress this without a fiddle to explain so I have closed this one and started afresh (seemed easier and clearer).  I think Pablo has the gist of my problem but I just couldn't fix it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718714/updating-d3-force-layouts-adding-and-removing-nodes-corrupt-the-page for the new question.